# Objective C Methods How To

Tags: objective-c, ios, function

I've some question regarding Objective C in Xcode 4.2.

How do I correctly call a class member method. For example if I had a class called MyClass with a method draw. At the moment i'm trying this.

```
MyClass *myclass;

myclass = [MyClass alloc];

[myclass draw];
```

I can't be creating my class instance correctly because a breakpoint in the draw method is never reached.

I'm also curious as to where the `main function` calls occur in an Xcode 4.2 project. If I wanted to make a game with a function called setup where would I call setup?

Any help appreciated as i'm trying to familiarize with Xcode and Objective C.

Comment: the `main function` is in main.m

Comment: @VinceBurn true but I don't think that's what Dave actually wants to know - he's asking about making games. He really needs `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the app delegate.

Comment: Yes Tim that was what I was looking for =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send the `init` message to initialize the object:

```
MyClass *myclass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myclass draw];
```

A rarely used option is the `new` method, which is a combination of `alloc` and `init`:

```
MyClass *myclass = [MyClass new];
[myclass draw];
```

The latter is shorter, but unconventional as it can be confusing when using Objective-C++. Also see the [`NSObject` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

---

For your setup method, you can set up things in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method of your application delegate (or in the `main` function in a daemon or command line application). Xcode's templates have the `main` function in a file called `main.m`.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective C, you must always initialize objects. Therefore the middle line should read

```
myclass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Otherwise the code snippet is fine (expect for the potential memory leak of `myclass`).

Additionally, there is a difference between class methods (called on `MyClass`) and instance methods (called on `myclass`). You can look through the documentation for many examples of this.